# iOS WatchKit and static library categories

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a WatchKit app that uses static library. The problem is when I call a method of a category in this static library, there is this exception :

```
+[NSDate stringFromDate:withFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xf12b0c
```

`stringFromDate:withFormat:` is a category method of the NSDate class, defined in the static library. Everything works with other classes but not with the categories. Also calling the method from a iOS application works fine.

Comment: Did you have to do anything special to get the static library to build for the Watch? So far I have been unable to get it to build correctly. The library works for the main project, but not for the watch extension.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by setting -ObjC flag in "other linker flags".

Comment: Which target did you set the -Objc flag?

Comment: Watchkit Extension target